# Why is this the cost?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, quicksort

The algorithm of the Quicksort is:

```
Quicksort(A,p,r)
      if p<r then
         q<- partition(A,p,r)
         Quicksort(A,p,q-1)
         Quicksort(A,q+1,r)
```

According to my notes,the cost of Quicksort(A,1,n) is T(n)=T(q)+T(n-q)+ cost of partition.

Why is the cost like that and not : T(n)=T(q-1)+T(n-q)+cost of partition?

And also why is the cost of the worst case T(n)=T(n-1)+Θ(n) ?

Comment: Your notes are inconsistently using `q` as both an index between `p` and `r` and the number of elements in the first half of the portion to sort.

Comment: My guess is that in the notes the constant term -1 is just disregarded, which is common in complexity analysis, and (I think) it does not affect the overall complexity of the algorithm. @user1990169 answers the 2nd question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm more confident about the answer to your second question.

In the worst case, the pivot can always turn out to be the lowest number (or the highest number) in the array. In that case, the divided arrays shall be of length n-1 and 0 respectively. Hence the recurrence relation shall be:

```
T(n)= T(n-1)+T(0) + Work done for partition
    = T(n-1) + 0 + O(n)
```

For example in the worst case if the array is originally sorted in ascended order and you decide to choose the 1st element as the pivot always.

```
Initial Array: {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
Pivot Element: 1.
Partitioned arrays: {} and {2,3,4,5}
Next pivot element: 2
Partitioned arrays: {} {3,4,5}
...
```

Here you can see that at each partition, the size of problem decreases by just 1 and not by a factor of half.

```
Hence T(n) = T(n-1) + Work done for partitioning( O(n) )
```

Comment: I haven`t understood it..could you explain it further to me?

Comment: Example added to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

1. Only the terms with the highest indices are considered when performing time complexity analysis. This is because only the terms with the highest indices remain relevant as the input gets larger. For example: `O(0.0001n^3 + 0.002n^2 + 0.1n + 1000000) = O(n^3)`. It follows that `T(q-1) = T(q)`, since `-1` is irrelevant for large values of `q`.
2. I am not sure if your note is entirely accurate. user1990169 has kindly answered why the general Quicksort has the worst case time complexity of `O(n^2)`, but it's actually possible to spend `O(n)` time to determine the median in an unsorted array of `n` elements, meaning we can always pick the median value (the best value) for the pivot in each iteration. The time complexity of `T(n)=T(n-1)+Θ(n)` may result from an array where all elements have the same value, in which case, depending on implementation, all elements other than the pivot may get put into the *LEFT* partition or the *RIGHT* partition. However, even this can be avoided with some clever implementation. Thus the complexity analysis of `T(n)=T(n-1)+Θ(n)` may be from a specific implementation of Quicksort, rather than an optimal one.